# Rails 4 - Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Users::TodosController

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

besides using devise for authentification w standard  Devise routes.. , I added the follwoing

```
  namespace :users do
     resources :todos
  end
```

to magane todos for the current user.
the generated routes are fine ...

```
                   users_todos GET        /users/todos(.:format)                    users/todos#index
                           POST       /users/todos(.:format)                    users/todos#create
            new_users_todo GET        /users/todos/new(.:format)                users/todos#new
           edit_users_todo GET        /users/todos/:id/edit(.:format)           users/todos#edit
                users_todo GET        /users/todos/:id(.:format)                users/todos#show
                           PATCH      /users/todos/:id(.:format)                users/todos#update
                           PUT        /users/todos/:id(.:format)                users/todos#update
                           DELETE     /users/todos/:id(.:format)                users/todos#destroy
```

once the user is logged in  , he is redirected to his todos#index list .. (users_todos_url)

```
 def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
     ....
      elsif resource.is_a?(User) && Settings.permit_user_login 
         stored_location_for(resource) || users_todos_url
         ....
```

but then , the error is raised .... and it's stated in the log :

```
Started GET "/users/todos" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-22 14:29:15 +0200

LoadError - Unable to autoload constant Users::TodosController, expected /Users/yves/bitbucket/railsTests/todoapp/app/controllers/users/todos_controller.rb to define it:
```

I have a users/todo_controller.rb

```
class User::TodosController < ApplicationController
..
 def index
sort_order = "updated_at DESC , title"
    todos = Todo.where(:user_id => current_user[:id]).order(sort_order).page params[:page]
end
```

Comment: With an error like that, what's inside the methods is probably not relevant, but anything outside of the methods (ie the code that gets executed when the class gets loaded) may be relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Log says todo **s** _controller.rb.

Controller names are plural form.

Comment: Thanks a lot .. did not noticed it... even if my Users folder is correctly written... Users...